# soft $Z_2$ symmetry breaking in the context of the Two-Higgs doublets model

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, supersymmetry, higgs

Imposing additional symmetries to the Higgs doublets in the Two-Higgs doublets model, like the $Z_2$ symmetry, aims to reduce the number of parameters in the potential. But it is said that the mass term $m^2_{12}$ term breaks it "*softly*" what is the meaning of softly in this particular case ?

Comment: Look at this answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/421945/47373 for what we mean by "soft".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, imposing $Z_2$ on the two Higgs doublet model (2HDM) is usually a strategy to prevent flavor changing neutral currents, which are very restricted by experiment. Alternatively, it is also a way of impose CP invariance in the model.

With this in mind, $Z_2$ symmetry removes the lagrangian parameters $\lambda_6$, $\lambda_7$ and $m_{12}$ (as they are usually denominated). This is an exact symmetry on the theory. When considering $m_{12}\neq 0$, we are still retaining CP conservation on the theory, but we "softly" break $Z_2$ as to keep the desired physical properties of the model but not oversimplifying it.